# Are there registers of the scores and participation in ancient Olympic games?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-greece, olympics

There are sources listing who (i.e. which country) participated in each Modern Olympic Game and the scores achieved by them.

Does such data exist for the Ancient Olympic Games? Are there information about who participated and who won what? If there are such information, were they compiled and recorded by a "organizational team" or something similar, or were they eventually mentioned by spectator authors in their accounts?

Comment: Some limited information does still survive, although nothing like that for modern Olympic games.. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ancient_Olympic_victors) provides a good overview.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Olympic_Games) page has very good details about this.

**ORIGIN**-

> They were held in honor of Zeus, and the Greeks gave them a mythological origin. The first Olympics is traditionally dated to 776 BC.

**EVENTS**- 
There were many events in Ancient Olympic games. There is one page available which contains the list of victors in events, but it is not in very good condition. You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Olympic_Games#/media/File%3AOlympic_victors_on_Papyrus_1185.jpg)

**FAMOUS ATHLETES**-

There were several participants in the Olympics events, some of them are mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Olympic_Games)-

> **From Sparta**
>
> 1- Cynisca of Sparta (owner of a four-horse chariot) (first woman to be listed as an Olympic victor).
>
> **From Rhodes**:
>
> 1- Diagoras of Rhodes (boxing 79th Olympiad, 464 BC) and his sons Akusilaos and Damagetos (boxing and pankration).
>
> 2- Leonidas of Rhodes (running: stadion, diaulos and hoplitodromos)(His record of 12 individual olympic titans was broken in 2016 by Michael Phelps who received his 13th original title.[79]).
>
> **From Croton**:
>
> 1-Astylos of Croton (running: stadion, diaulos and hoplitodromos).
>
> 2-Milo of Croton (wrestling).
>
> 3-Timasitheos of Croton (wrestling).
>
> **From other cities/kingdoms:**
>
> 1-Koroibos of Elis (stadion, the very first Olympic champion).
>
> 2-Orsippus of Megara (running: diaulos).
>
> 3-Theagenes of Thasos (boxer, pankratiast and runner).
>
> 4-Alexander I of Macedon (running: stadion) [81].
>
> **Non-Greek:**
>
> 1-Tiberius (steerer of a four-horse chariot)[82].
>
> 2-Nero (steerer of a ten-horse chariot).
>
> 3-Varastades, Prince and future King of Armenia, last known Ancient Olympic victor (boxing) during the 291st Olympic Games in the 4th century.

Apart from this there is another source which tells about the number of events and it's winners. The list can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ancient_Olympic_victors)

Answer (score 11):

To add to the first answer, there is no single registry of athletes who performed in the Olympic or various other pan-Hellenic games. I am sure though that there have been attempts by modern researchers to compile such a list.

In Sparta today you can see on the main street a monument dedicated to all the past Spartan Olympic victors to the present day. I took a photo of it when i went there in 2016.

Name of Athlete -  Contest - Year (π.Χ is BC and μ.Χ is AD )

[image]